# dbms_random string never changing seed

Tags: oracle, random, passwords

I'm trying to generate random passwords for new users and i have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO LOGIN t (t.userID, t.password)
SELECT DISTINCT u.userID, (select dbms_random.string('U', 10) str from dual)
FROM USERS u
where u.userID IS NOT NULL
```

But the problem is that the dbms_random.string generates a new random code the first time i run the query, but it keeps the same seed for the rest of the INSERT.

How can i make PLSQL make it change at any iteration? I never used it in Oracle.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery

```
(select dbms_random.string('U', 10) str from dual)
```

is only going to be executed once, with the same value then available to every inserted row. You don't need a subquery though:

```
INSERT INTO LOGIN t (t.userID, t.password)
SELECT DISTINCT u.userID, dbms_random.string('U', 10)
FROM USERS u
where u.userID IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle demo of the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31997).

If `userID` is the primary key then you don't need the `distinct`.

You shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext, you should be storing a hashed (and seeded) version. Obviously you need to know the plaintext to tell the users if you're generating them, but you shouldn't be storing them like that, and you should be forcing the users to change them immediately too.